# Release apk generating in yml script

Tags: apk, release, gitlab-ci-runner

Iam trying to generate a release apk thorugh yml script.
1.First i prepared windows mahcine and installed android studio
2.I can able to generate the release apk in GUI Mode and cmd prompt , but i can't able to generate the release apk through yml script. below error iam facing from more than a week.

```
> Task :app:processReleaseMainManifest
[com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:12.0.1] C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\59903d787d40edbded5d0ceb720c9856\transformed\jetified-play-services-tagmanager-12.0.1\AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
    Package name 'com.google.android.gms.tagmanager' used in: com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:12.0.1, com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-api:12.0.1.
C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\ks7wyRV9\0\buildprocess\spectoapk\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:28:5-65 Warning:
    Element uses-permission#android.permission.VIBRATE at AndroidManifest.xml:28:5-65 duplicated with element declared at AndroidManifest.xml:22:5-66
> Task :app:processReleaseManifest
> Task :communicator:compileReleaseLibraryResources
> Task :app:processReleaseManifestForPackage
> Task :specto:compileReleaseLibraryResources
> Task :app:extractProguardFiles
> Task :communicator:bundleLibResRelease
> Task :specto:bundleLibCompileToJarRelease
> Task :app:processReleaseResources FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform play-services-cast-framework-12.0.1.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:12.0.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\5364af0121771b691531e78f2f9a3c16\transformed\jetified-play-services-cast-framework-12.0.1.
         > Android resource compilation failed
           ERROR:AAPT: C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\8635cf2c80352829dcd09901c7b21377\transformed\com.google.android.gms.cast.framework: error: The system cannot find the file specified. (2).
           
               
   > Failed to transform play-services-cast-12.0.1.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:12.0.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\c144de37d49f3842b4e142ad74da822b\transformed\jetified-play-services-cast-12.0.1.
         > Android resource compilation failed
           ERROR:AAPT: C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\f0288fa25f3e4abb12b0e471975b9ed0\transformed\com.google.android.gms.cast: error: The system cannot find the file specified. (2).
           
               
   > Failed to transform play-services-cast-12.0.1.aar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:12.0.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\c144de37d49f3842b4e142ad74da822b\transformed\jetified-play-services-cast-12.0.1.
         > Android resource compilation failed
           ERROR:AAPT: C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\f0288fa25f3e4abb12b0e471975b9ed0\transformed\com.google.android.gms.cast: error: The system cannot find the file specified. (2).
```

1. I tried upgrading the JDK and downgrading the JDK
2. I deleted gradle cache and newly downloadled
3. Now iam trying in bumble bee version , i tried with latest version also iguna , same issue ..

Comment: Is it possible that the used Gitlab runner is executed as service with SYSTEM permissions? Gradle seems to expect a common user profile so I would create a regular Windows user account and let the runner run in this account. Then most likely some of the paths problems should vanish.

Comment: Issue fixed , After adding the  gradlew home url in yml script , pipeline triggered successfully ( gradlew assembleRelease -g C:\Users\build\.gradle\caches )